Which Wifi 6E internal antenna?
This thread is related to this one, so maybe taking a quick look at it may be useful.
Recently, I've changed my AC3160NGW to an AX210NGW, precisely, this one. And, although the Bluetooth functionality works just fine, the wifi simply doesn't, which I think it is due to the 6E network card function, since the laptop is quite old, and possibly its wifi antenna does not support the 6E.
I would like to know if someone could help me to find a laptop internal antenna with wifi 6E support. Because, when searching for such items in online stores, I always find antennas with the NGFF word in the item title, however, I am not sure if such antennas work with NGWs.

In your other thread you're going through a whole problem with detecting the WiFi adapter at all. Did you finally resolve that? If the device isn't being detected you need to fix that before worrying about the antenna. A 5 Ghz antenna should be adequate for proving the device works and getting connected. You only need a special antenna for 6E if you're actually connecting to a 6 Ghz 6E SSID.

Thank you so much. Thanks for taking the time for reading the thread. Well, the problem is that the bluetooth works, but the wifi not, and, furthermore, the computer starts just fine with no warning from the BIOS, which, theoretically, it says no issue with whitelist. However, I do not see any other barrier other than the BIOS, so I was trying a different BIOS, like coreboot ou libreboot, since the vendor BIOS I am using is already updated.

However, coreboot has an issue with braswell, which is the graphic card of my laptop. Therefore, I could put the work to manage coreboot settings for my braswell (which would take days, due to my lack of knowledge doing this), or simply give up.

No one will replace the built-in internal antenna cabling in laptops/notebooks. Think about an external device on a USB port, e.g. https://aliexpress.com/item/1005006132255563.html

Thank you so much.

There are a few reasons why this will not work.

You can't just change the antenna to support a newer version of Wifi.  The required code is also different.
The Bios will have a list of hardware capability. It will tell the OS that the hardware does not support 6E, even if you change the antenna.

The easy option is to upgrade your laptop.

Thank for the comment. Concerning the BIOS case, are you talking about the BIOS whitelist? If so, AFAIK, case such device is out of its whitelist, then a message should be warned right at the boot, which did not happen.
